# Kinect gesture recognition

Tags: kinect, gesture-recognition, xbox360

I just want to know whether identification of objects like humans and gestures of body parts  is done by Kinect or by the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done on the Xbox.
The Kinect only sends a depth map, rgb video and sound, which are processed by Microsoft's algorithms on the Xbox.

[OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/) comes with some tools (e.g. NITE) that do skeleton tracking and some gesture recognition for you, if you plan to program for the Kinect.